# Complex Infinity of Hypergeometric+Gamma function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I am solving some integral which gives an hypergeometric function+gamma function . The point is that my values of `n` (see the code below) are integers, so `n = 1,2,3,4...`. But it gives complex singularity when I want to introduce the value of `n` in the expression once the integral has been already computed.

```
f[r_, k_, kl_, n_] := Sin[k*kl*r]/(k^2*r)*k^-n
Integration[r_, kl_, n_, m_] := 
 Assuming[{kl > 0, n > 0, r > 0, m > 0}, 
   Integrate[f[r, k, kl, n], {k, 1, m}]] // FullSimplify

function[r_] := Integration[r, kl, n, Infinity] // FullSimplify
function[r]
```

The result is :

```
-kl (kl r)^n Cos[(n \[Pi])/2] Gamma[-1 - n] + (
 kl HypergeometricPFQ[{-(n/2)}, {3/2, 1 - n/2}, -(1/4) kl^2 r^2])/n
```

So *Mathematica* can solve the integral for any value of `n`. But when I substitue in this expression the value of `n` that I want then I get a singularity (of course, due to the gamma function and the hypergeometric function)

```
-kl (kl r)^n Cos[(n \[Pi])/2] Gamma[-1 - n] + (
  kl HypergeometricPFQ[{-(n/2)}, {3/2, 1 - n/2}, -(1/4) kl^2 r^2])/
  n /. n -> 2
```

I get

`Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity encountered.`

But I don't undersrtand, since If I perform the integral given the value of `n` already, then I get an analityical expression for that

```
f[r_, k_, kl_, n_] := Sin[k*kl*r]/(k^2*r)*k^-n
Integration[r_, kl_, n_, m_] := 
 Assuming[{kl > 0, n > 0, r > 0, m > 0}, 
   Integrate[f[r, k, kl, n], {k, 1, m}]] // FullSimplify

function[r_] := Integration[r, kl, 2, Infinity] // FullSimplify
function[r]
```

I get:

```
(kl r Cos[kl r] + 
 kl^3 r^3 CosIntegral[kl r] + (2 - kl^2 r^2) Sin[kl r])/(6 r)
```

And there is not any kind of singularity in this expression. So my question is: There is some way to get a general expression in terms of the variable `n`, without get a singular behaviour as happens due to the Gamma and the Hypergeometric function? *Mathematica* can simplify this expression in order to cancel the divergences?

Comment: I am currently not at a machine with *Mathematica* to check, but a cursory look at your integrand tells me that you could try using the complex exponential representation of $\sin$ to derive an expression in terms of the [generalized exponential integral $E_p(z)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19) (which *Mathematica* implements as `ExpIntegralE[]`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a further condition `Element[n, Integers]` in `Integration`, then the integral for $m=\infty$ returns exponential integral functions, not singular hypergeometric/Gamma functions:

```
f[r_, k_, kl_, n_] := Sin[k*kl*r]/(k^2*r)*k^-n
Integration[r_, kl_, n_, m_] := 
  Assuming[{kl > 0, n > 0, r > 0, m > 0, Element[n, Integers]}, 
    Integrate[f[r, k, kl, n], {k, 1, m}]] // FullSimplify

function[r_] := Integration[r, kl, n, Infinity] // FullSimplify
function[r]
```

> (I (-ExpIntegralE[2 + n, -I kl r] + ExpIntegralE[2 + n, I kl r]))/(2 r)

This should solve your problem.

Further, if you use direct assignments `=` instead of delayed assignments `:=` then your code only has to do one integration instead of a new one for every value of $m$.

Comment: Okay thank your very much!!